# Multiple BSOD issues (Windbg included)

Tags: bsod, windbg

I have been experiencing multiple BSOD issues, the latest one was;

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA   What failed: portcls.sys

The issues were occurring when rendering high intensive games but now the BSOD will happen just on idle. My rig is custom built;
GPU: GTX 970 Strix

CPU: Intel 2ndGen i7 2600k (1155socket sandybridge 3.4GHZ)

RAM: 16Gb razor(2 x 8GB DDR3)

MOBO: ASRock Z77 Extreme 6

PSU: Crosair CX750W

Storage: OCZ-VERTTEX4 250GB SSD & PNY CS900 120GB SSD

I have been told to analysis my dumps file through Windbg tool so ih ave made an attempt, in no way am i saying i'm a professional at this but i have tried to open the file via the tool as follows;

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17674.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\060118-7984-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 17134 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`b6416000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`b67d32f0
Debug session time: Fri Jun  1 15:14:03.303 2018 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 3 days 0:18:39.188
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
............................................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
..................................................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 50, {ffff978a7f402008, 0, fffff80354299631, c}

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for vrtaucbl.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for vrtaucbl.sys

Could not read faulting driver name
Probably caused by : portcls.sys ( portcls!GetMaxMapRegisters+5 )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff800`b65ad680 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:0018:ffffd10d`b6c3cb10=0000000000000050
2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except.
Typically the address is just plain bad or it is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffff978a7f402008, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: fffff80354299631, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
    address.
Arg4: 000000000000000c, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


Could not read faulting driver name

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

SYSTEM_SKU:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  P2.80

BIOS_DATE:  07/01/2013

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASRock

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Z77 Extreme6

BASEBOARD_VERSION:                        

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: ffff978a7f402008

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff80354299631

BUGCHECK_P4: c

READ_ADDRESS: fffff800b6873388: Unable to get MiVisibleState
Unable to get NonPagedPoolStart
Unable to get NonPagedPoolEnd
Unable to get PagedPoolStart
Unable to get PagedPoolEnd
 ffff978a7f402008 

FAULTING_IP: 
portcls!GetMaxMapRegisters+5
fffff803`54299631 8b4150          mov     eax,dword ptr [rcx+50h]

MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  c

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: d48

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 2a

CPU_STEPPING: 7

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,2a,7,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 29'00000000 (cache) 29'00000000 (init)

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  AV

PROCESS_NAME:  audiodg.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-622S1FA

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  06-01-2018 15:41:23.0227

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.17674.1000 amd64fre

TRAP_FRAME:  ffffd10db6c3cdc0 -- (.trap 0xffffd10db6c3cdc0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=ffff3e7e9aff0a5d rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffff978a7f401fb8
rdx=fffff803542b4980 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80354299631 rsp=ffffd10db6c3cf58 rbp=ffff978a81925510
 r8=fffff803542b49a0  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000001
r11=ffffd10db6c3cf50 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
portcls!GetMaxMapRegisters+0x5:
fffff803`54299631 8b4150          mov     eax,dword ptr [rcx+50h] ds:ffff978a`7f402008=????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800b65f1d39 to fffff800b65ad680

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd10d`b6c3cb08 fffff800`b65f1d39 : 00000000`00000050 ffff978a`7f402008 00000000`00000000 ffffd10d`b6c3cdc0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd10d`b6c3cb10 fffff800`b64876d8 : ffff978a`79a7df6c 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffbc5e`2f178bc0 : nt!MiSystemFault+0x16eb89
ffffd10d`b6c3cc50 fffff800`b65bc9c7 : ffff978a`7a7059b8 fffff803`542b4980 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`85c6a8a8 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x1f8
ffffd10d`b6c3cdc0 fffff803`54299631 : fffff803`542e2254 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`81925510 ffff978a`85c6a7e0 : nt!KiPageFault+0x3c7
ffffd10d`b6c3cf58 fffff803`542e2254 : 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`81925510 ffff978a`85c6a7e0 ffff978a`85c6a8d0 : portcls!GetMaxMapRegisters+0x5
ffffd10d`b6c3cf60 fffff803`542e1135 : 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`8337b220 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`8337b220 : portcls!CPortPinWavePci::Init+0x3b4
ffffd10d`b6c3d000 fffff803`542c5ae7 : ffff978a`85c6a7e0 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`7b09cb80 ffff978a`7c0eb960 : portcls!CPortFilterWavePci::NewIrpTarget+0x195
ffffd10d`b6c3d080 fffff803`542c4c6e : 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`00000001 ffff978a`7c0f0e80 00000000`00000002 : portcls!xDispatchCreate+0x2c7
ffffd10d`b6c3d130 fffff803`54357199 : ffff978a`7b09cb80 ffff978a`7b09cd02 ffffd10d`b6c3d558 ffff978a`7c0eb810 : portcls!KsoDispatchCreateWithGenericFactory+0x2e
ffffd10d`b6c3d160 fffff803`542c5bd9 : ffff978a`7c0eb810 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`7c0eb960 ffff978a`00000000 : ks!KsDispatchIrp+0x289
ffffd10d`b6c3d220 fffff803`52cc60a1 : ffff978a`7c0eb810 ffff978a`7b09cb80 ffff978a`7a5ee568 ffff978a`7b09cb80 : portcls!PcDispatchIrp+0xd9
ffffd10d`b6c3d290 ffff978a`7c0eb810 : ffff978a`7b09cb80 ffff978a`7a5ee568 ffff978a`7b09cb80 00000000`00000000 : vrtaucbl+0x60a1
ffffd10d`b6c3d298 ffff978a`7b09cb80 : ffff978a`7a5ee568 ffff978a`7b09cb80 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xffff978a`7c0eb810
ffffd10d`b6c3d2a0 ffff978a`7a5ee568 : ffff978a`7b09cb80 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`85202700 : 0xffff978a`7b09cb80
ffffd10d`b6c3d2a8 ffff978a`7b09cb80 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`85202700 ffff978a`7b09cb80 : 0xffff978a`7a5ee568
ffffd10d`b6c3d2b0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 ffff978a`85202700 ffff978a`7b09cb80 ffff978a`7a5ee4d0 : 0xffff978a`7b09cb80


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  7b9a271fe2504448b64e7d9108022dc584b70198

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  df8b59b83c70540432d0cce4be780740da6b574c

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  64cf83bef7e45c5f15b7280767badbb262226f80

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
portcls!GetMaxMapRegisters+5
fffff803`54299631 8b4150          mov     eax,dword ptr [rcx+50h]

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  c350418b

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4

SYMBOL_NAME:  portcls!GetMaxMapRegisters+5

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: portcls

IMAGE_NAME:  portcls.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  d3dae7d

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.17134.48

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  5

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_R_INVALID_portcls!GetMaxMapRegisters

BUCKET_ID:  AV_R_INVALID_portcls!GetMaxMapRegisters

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  AV_R_INVALID_portcls!GetMaxMapRegisters

TARGET_TIME:  2018-06-01T14:14:03.000Z

OSBUILD:  17134

OSSERVICEPACK:  81

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2018-05-20 12:23:46

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  180410-1804

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs4_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  d06c

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:av_r_invalid_portcls!getmaxmapregisters

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {349f0185-3933-3949-d141-0476525399d9}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

I'm not 100% sure if i preformed that correctly but i did open the source file for the dump through %SystemRoot%\Minidump.

Many thanks in advance,

JD

Comment: Do you have Ventrillo installed? `vrtaucbl.sys` belongs to `Ventrilo`, which is making an unsupported call more than likely, which is causing `portcls.sys` to crash your system.  Which makes sense because the ` audiodg.exe` was running also and is linked to the crash.  In other words, you have an audio device issue, verify all audio drivers are updated and specifically support Windows 10 1803

Comment: @Ramhound i Use adobe audtion to run a Virtual Audio Cable to Discord, but i was told by a windows agent that the issue maybe lies with the windows 1803 patch and a driver issue. How can i verify my sound drivers? Thanks!

Comment: Ventrillo was the first result I found linked to `vrtaucbl.sys` other programs like Discord or TS might use it.  If those applications are not running does the system crash?  The system file is `Virtual Audio Cable` which means other applications could be using it

Comment: The system has always crashed with Discord or TS running, i do use a 3rd party Virtual Audio Cable aswell if this could be the issue? @Ramhound

Comment: Yes, the system file associated vrtaucbl.sys is causing portcls.sys to crash your system.  You have confirmed you are running applications that are likely candidates that are causing the crash.  Which is the reason I asked, if those applications are not running, does the system crash?

Comment: @Ramhound I always have discord running so it's hard to say sorry. Since the crash around a hour ago i havn't had one since and not yet opened Discord. I have been using that software for over a year now and never had this issue, why do you think the problem would just occur now? Thanks

Comment: I can't help you.  The comment section is the improper place to continue this discussion.  I have given you all the help I can in the comment section.

Comment: I'll follow your line of advice about sound drivers as unfortunately my rep is too low to start a chat. Thanks for the input @Ramhound